# Python: can't find '__main__' module in '.'

Tags: python, curl

I try to execute this script directly via curl, but this fails:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guettli/fix-CVE-2020-15228/main/fix_CVE_2020_15228.py | python3  .

/srv/zulip-py3-venv/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in '.'
(23) Failed writing body
```

What's wrong?

It works if I do it in two step (download the file, then execute it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `-` missing.

This works:

```
curl -sSL https://.../foo.py | python3 - .
```